# Is there a way to compare Haskell and C functions via AutoBench?

Tags: c, haskell, benchmarking, autobench

I am used to benchmark Haskell functions via AutoBench but I haven't found so far any info about comparing Haskell and C with it.

In particular, I need to benchmark 2 functions and feed them with a random Int list (or array in C). From what I have seen people often compare the runtime of functions with the time unix command (which seems to me completely wrong if you want to get a precise benchmark).

Does anyone know a way or have a suggestion to benchmark functions from these 2 languages via AutoBench?

Comment: *AutoBench is a tool for comparing the time performance of two or more Haskell programs* - this is from its description. So it is for comparing Haskell vs Haskell. Perhaps you can write Haskell wrapper for C function using the [Foreign Function interface](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried. The problem I am facing is that marshalling adds a considerable amount of overhead just to C functions and as I need a common interface from which infer input cases, I haven't come up with a solution.

Comment: Could you stick the data in pinned arrays and have both Haskell and C functions use that? You'll have to change your Haskell functions to use arrays instead of lists, but that may well be a performance win anyway.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes it would be a solution but in my case, I have to compare 2 Quicksort versions to point out how linked lists can change performances and working with arrays would change the result. It is a very rare case...

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like this? https://github.com/lehins/haskell-quicksort which has a comparison of quicksort in Haskell (both arrays and lists). There is also comparison to C implementation over FFI which is currently commented out because naive C implementation doesn't handle an already sorted array too well.

Comment: @Gianmarco, please let me know if you'll be able to beat the version that uses `massiv` ;)